# Внешняя ссылка внутри SVG, выведенного через object

Tags: svg, ссылки

Есть svg, он выведен на html-страницу сайта через `<object>`.
Внутри него есть ссылка `<a xlink:href="внешнийУРЛ" target="_top">текст</a>` которая ссылается на другую страницу сайта.
В итоге, при клике на эту ссылку открывается нужная страница, но в рамках всё того же `<object>`, то есть вроде как, через фрейм на старой странице.
Вопрос - как сделать переход по ссылке с открытием новой страницы? По техническим причинам, svg нужно выводить только object'ом.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<body>
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="example.svg" width="500" height="500"></object>
</body>
```

svg:

```
<svg height="512pt" width="512pt" viewBox="0 -56 512 512"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <text><a xlink:href="https://google.com" target="_top">google</a></text>

</svg>
```

---

локально в хроме работает как ожидается, в сниппете тут переход не происходит вообще

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin
>   'https://ru.stackoverflow.com' from frame with URL
>   'https://strangerintheq.github.io/svg-object-embed/example.svg'. The
>   frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but
>   the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or
>   'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://strangerintheq.github.io/svg-object-embed/example.svg" width="500" height="500"></object>
```